# How many planes are determined by n points if no 4 of the points are coplanar?

Tags: combinations

I have $n$ points in space, no $4$ of which are coplanar. How many distinct planes are determined by these $n$ points?

My thoughts: 3 noncollinear points determine a plane. Therefore, it is C(n,3)?

Comment: Yes. $\!\!\!\!$

Comment: But if I change the question ,say, 4 points can be coplanar.Is the answer :C(n,4)?

Comment: No, and worse, if we allow coplanar tetrads of points, the count depends on their configuration. For four coplanar points, there is only $1$ distinct plane; for four noncoplanar points there are, by your formula $C(4, 3) = 4$ planes.